# Date.UTC creating wrong dates

Tags: javascript, date, graph, rgraph

I've written some code for a dynamically created graph and it uses Date.UTC() to create formatted dates.

It works completely fine within months, however I'm having trouble with crossing over months, i.e. Feb to March creates 29th, 30th and 31st Feb and now I have found an error that makes the 31st May 1st June.......

I've tried to find an answer but no luck yet. Is there a simple fix that I am overlooking or is there a fix?

```
s.Set('chart.xmin', Date.UTC(<?php echo $startyear.",".$startmonth.",".$startday.",".$starthour.",".$startminute; ?>));            
    s.Set('chart.xmax', Date.UTC(<?php echo $finishyear.",".$finishmonth.",".$finishday.",".$finishhour.",".$finishminute; ?>));
```

Cheers

James

Comment: Maybe you're expecting the wrong output; `Date.UTC` gives you an _Integer_ in _ms_ since the unix epoch, not a _Date_ instance. Perhaps your function expects `new Date(Date.UTC(y, m, d, h, min, s))`

Comment: Thanks Paul. The Date.UTC is formated later on in the script. It all works within a month like between 5th and 20th May, the problem starts when we cross over months and invalid or wrong dates are created.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript months are 0-11, while PHP's are 1-12.  So when you generate JavaScript code in a PHP page, you'll need to subtract 1 from the month.

But wouldn't it be easier to just pass a timestamp?  For example:

```
new Date(<?php echo date_timestamp_get($yourdate) * 1000 ?>)
```

The `* 1000` is there because PHP's timestamp is in seconds and JavaScript's is in milliseconds.  But they both use the same reference date - the `1/1/1970 UTC` epoch.

Reference PHP `date_timestamp_get` [docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have done that and it all works if the range remains within a month. It is when the range crosses over the month I get the problem. It makes 31st May the 1st June and adds 29th 20th and 31st February which are all invalid dates

Comment: Really? You aren't showing a `-1` anywhere. in the code.  Also, why do you need to pass it as separate values?  Wouldn't it be much easier to pass a single integer timestamp?